# Enter debugging mode on next action

Tags: debugging

I have a problem with my screenshots not showing in my org-file in emacs 29

[image]

If I click on attachment link an empty buffer opens. I would like to investigate the problem. I would like to start by going into a debug mode, but I just found, I can only go into the debug mode, when I know the function, but I do not even know, which function is called.

What should I do now?

Comment: `C-h k` and click the link, then you know what function will be called.

Comment: You can enter the debugger any time, by evaluating `(debug)`.